# Gvim <C-]> not working with azerty keyboard

Tags: key-bindings, keyboard-layout

I have a windows 7 machine with an azerty keyboard running gVim 7.4

My problem is that `<C-]>` simply does nothing: When I'm in an help page I can't follow the tags links. As I have an azerty keyboard I have to use the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> I thought that was causing the problem but when I use Vim on a distant machine via ssh in a cygwin console `<C-]>` works properly.

**Edit:** It also works correctly when I use a local vim instance in a cygwin console. So it seems to be a gVim issue.

I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562654/vim-ctrl-keys-not-working) mentionning this problem but none of the answers works for me.

Also I used `:verbose nmap <C-]>` to check if a mapping was already present but I gave me `no mapping found`.

What can I do to have this key combinaison working properly?

Comment: Try the `$` key in place of `]`: `<C-$>`.

Comment: If you're using Windows, it's possible the `<C-]>` is not defined in the keyboard layout i.e. it doesn't generate a code for Vim to pick up. You can probably change the keyboard layout using MS keyboard layout creator tool, in order to add the missing code(s), but I didn't try that, just read about it some time ago. Or, you can map `<C-]>` to another combo.

Comment: @romainl: This alternative key sequence works thanks! @ Laser: as the solution of romainl worked I'll probably will not take time to redefine my layout but I have a question: If windows doesn't send a code for this combo, how can it work on a cygwin console?

Comment: It's Vim's fault: `]` is hardcoded to the last key on the first alphabetical row.

Comment: According to a recent discussion on vim_use, `langmap` might help.

Comment: @lcd047: I just read the help entry for `langmap` I understand how it works but not how I should use it: I tried `set langmap+=]$` so `<C-]>` would become `<C-$>` but when I hit `<C-]>` that just put the cursor at the end of the line.

Comment: I don't know how is that supposed to work, but I'm pretty sure it isn't with key combinations.  [This page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_Vim_key_bindings_while_typing_non-latin1_text) seems relevant.  People have been passing around files with key definitions, maybe you can find one for AZERTY.

Comment: I can't find reference to azerty layout on your link but I'll look for it and post it when I find. Thanks!

Comment: @statox Can you make it an answer, even if it's not yet perfect?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel: Unfortunately it's more than imperfect since I did have the time to make `langmap` working properly... I will make an answer with romainl's solution and mentionning lcd047 suggestion but it will need to be improved when I have the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it was asked in the comment I'll leave here what I have done so far:

I'm using the solution suggested by @romainl in the comments which is using `<C-$>` instead of `<C-]>`. That might not be the most elegant way but it works and I haven't found any drawback for the moment.

I think it is important to also mention @lcd047's suggestion of using the option `langmap`. From what I understood this option allows to map a character to another. For example I tried to put this `set langmap+=]$` in my `vimrc` to let vim replace `]` with `$` but I haven't been able to make this solution work I will update this answer if I manage to make the second solution work or if I find a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Vim 9.0 (specifically **gvim**)  on Windows 10 (italian qwerty keyboard, but i think this is irrelevant).

Neither `:map` command nor Google helped me. :-(

#### gvim

- If i try to open link in the help file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>  (*key* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>) nothing happens.
  If I type it twice the cursor go at the bottom of the help file.
- If I type   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> the cursor go down by one row. Same behavior if I type only <kbd>+</kbd>.

#### vim

- As in gvim, if i try to open link in the help file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>  (*key* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>) nothing happens.
  And the same if I type it twice (the cursor go at the bottom of the help file).
- If I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> **it works!**, while if I just type <kbd>+</kbd> it behaves as gvim.

In both programs the mouse works properly.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+LeftClick or double LeftClick both leads me to the right help tag.

#### My workaround

I solved the problem by setting the mapping in the .vimrc

```
" Workaround to jump to the help tags in gvim
nnoremap <C-+> <C-]>
```

---

P.S. *I believe (but I'm not sure) that this problem came by installing the new vim version, with the previous one it seems to me that it worked fine, even if trying to use it now, downloading the zip of 8.2 in a folder and launching gvim the problem is present ... and I didn't remap the keys for Windows when the installer asked me.

I don't know but I am writing this in case anyone else notices any connection.*

Comment: There is currently a bug about `Ctrl-[` in Vim 9.:  [bug 10454](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/10454)

Comment: Thanks Vivian, good to know, but I'm not sure that it's related.  It happens, for me, also using the old 8.2, as I wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem for me, not being able to jump/reach an help subject in Vim with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> on **Windows 10** with an **AZERTY** keyboard and layout (french).

After many searches...

First my versions :

- Windows 10 Version 22H2 (build 19045.2846)
- Powershell 7.3.3 and Windows Terminal version 1.16.10261.0

With **Vim** 9.0.1425:

- gvim & vim => <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>$</kbd> **will jump to the help subject**.

With **Neovim** 0.9.0

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> (the key on the top right, with <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> and <kbd>}</kbd>) **will jump to the help subject**.

On a Linux system (**Ubuntu Mate**) with an AZERTY layout and keyboard and with Vim version 8.2.4919, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> runs, as expected and stated in the documentation.

Hope this help.